# Automatic loading of data in dropDownList using Yii framework?

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I study the book Yii. Such a situation:

Create an article.

There are main categories and sub-categories have, for example:

Technology (main) - Auto, 
                  - Motorcycles, 
                  - Bicycles
(Additional categories are included in the main category). Main categories 30, sub-categories 400. About 5 to 1 main subcategories.

In the process of creating an article, I have two dropDown list:

**_form.php**

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category_id', Category::allCategory()); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subcategory_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'subcategory_id', Subcategory::allCategory()); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'subcategory_id'); ?>
    </div>
```

I need when choosing a main category to automatically load these sub-categories in second dropDownList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here wiki article with solution

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/